# How to properly determine Amazon AWS Heroku subnets?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services

I need to be able to enable access through a firewall to a server for an app that is built atop Heroku.  Unfortunately the IP's coming from Heroku's AWS instances seem to vary quite a bit.  Is there a "correct" way of determining what subnet to expect from Heroku's AWS platform for an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unfortunate as this is -- there isn't a good way to continuously get this information. On the AWS forums, however, the EC2 engineers tend to occasionally post their IP ranges (here is a recent example: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701).

The downside to this, however, is that it requires a lot of manual work.

Comment: Nice, thanks for that info. It corroborated some data I already had and helped make what I did more robust.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to accept Heroku public IPs in firewalls. Even if there was, you would be compromising your application and opening up an attack vector via other apps on Heroku.

The solution is to have an adequate authentication layer in your exposed services.

Comment: First, I was hoping to only expose a particular compute cloud, not the entire AWS infrastructure.  Second, I have no other option in terms of an "adequate authentication layer" for this particular scenario as it is pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a few years ago back when services like Proximo didn’t exist -- or weren’t known within the Heroku community.

Today, if you want your outbound traffic to come through a static IP which you can whitelist in your firewall, you can use a proxy service like Proximo (Fixie is another example).

There are a few downsides for using these services:

### 1) Intrusive Setup

Although the setup of these addons is relatively simple, it’s important to understand how they affect the application.

In case of Proximo, for example, you’ll be required to wrap your processes in a special utility.
This utility will “automatically forward outbound TCP connections made by the wrapped process over your proxy.”

### 2) Latency

To make your outbound traffic come from a static IP, these services route the traffic through a proxy. This means you’ll add another hop to your outbound communication.

I know that applications that run on Heroku usually aren’t very sensitive to network latency, but it’s important to take this issue into a consideration.

### 3) Uptime

Although these services are relatively stable, it should be noted that routing the traffic through a specialized third-party proxy adds another point of failure and may affect the overall stability of your applications.

To summarize, these services will help you solve the problem. However, I would consider using them as a temporary workaround, not a complete solution.

Rest assured that these kinds of fixes can hold for a very long time, but if security becomes increasingly more important for the applications you’re running on Heroku, it can be a good idea to start planning a migration to AWS.

If you’re wondering when can be the best time for your team to make the transition to AWS, I’ve shared a few notes here: “[Will Heroku always be perfect?](https://opsfleet.com/topics/migrate-from-heroku-to-aws/when-should-you-migrate/)”

Hope that helps.