# Securing a publicly available RDS backend for a Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, rds

We currently have an RoR app hosted at Heroku, with an AWS RDS backend. Currently, the RDS instance is available to all inbound traffic.  To only allow traffic from my Heroku app, can I whitelist the applicable IP blocks here:

> https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

...or is an add-on like Proximo or QuotaGuard my only option?

Additionally, are there security concerns for having an RDS instance available to all incoming traffic, given that the RDS instance is password protected?

Comment: Ideally you should not expose your database to the world, or even to the (very wide) EC2 range of IPs, regardless of password protection. Can you get a fixed static IP for your app in Heroku that you can then whitelist in your RDS security group?

Comment: (off topic, but) Is that RDS backend working well with Heroku? Considering that move ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

As Jarmod’s comment suggests, it’s not advised to expose your database to the world, even if it’s password protected and the communication is encrypted. It’s not that your data is entirely exposed, but when dealing with sensitive information, it’s advised to control who can request access to the data in addition to the user/password authorization.

Unfortunately, when you run on Heroku you don’t have too many options. Even Heroku’s own Postgresql database is publically accessible if you know it’s url/endpoint.

If you want to improve security, you’ve two options:

#### 1) Use an outbound proxy addon

As you suggested, you can use a proxy addon such as Proximo or Fixie and configure AWS security groups to only accepts connections from the proxy's static IPs.

I’ve detailed the downsides of this approach in my reply to: “[How to properly determine Amazon AWS Heroku subnets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096840/883598)”

#### 2) Migrate your application from Heroku to AWS

Depending on your company size and product maturity, it might be a good idea to consider a migration from Heroku to AWS.

When your application’s stack is run entirely from within AWS, you’ll have much more control over security and can decide how far you want to go to protect your data.

I helped a few clients with similar migrations and security was one of the top 3 reasons to migrate from Heroku to AWS.

Hope that helps.